# How can I create a 3D dataset with different length size for arrays which I can access any element through it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, 3d, dataset

I tried implementing pandas and create a dataset using dataframe as following

```
{
'func1': [[12,5,9],[0.4,5,6]],
'func2': [[33,65,7],[5,0,23]]
}
```

But I couldn't access a number like `9` only for instance I could only get the whole `[12,5,9]` then I tried extracting it by converting it to a list

But my problem was the df requires a same length array, which is the best structure to create this dataset?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.